# Replacing Whitespace between Variables with Commas in Python

Tags: python

I want to remove the whitespace between each of the variables printed and replace them with commas.

In its current state, the string then each varable with a whitespace seperating them would be printed.

For example if a = 1 and each variable was an increase of 1 then this would be printed: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. I want it to print: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Here is the code I'm trying to change:

```
print("Test: ", a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Martijn's answer is the better way to do it, but just so you know this it's possible, the function `print` takes a keyword argument, `sep`, which specifies what to print between arguments between the function.

```
>>> print('Test:', a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i, sep=',')
Test:, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

As you can see, it also prints a comma after "Test:", which is probably not what you want.

Comment: That's exactly why I deleted my answer that was identical to this :) The other albeit messy option is to `print('Test': ', end='')` and then `print(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,sep=',')`

Comment: Right!  I would definitely opt for `",".join()`.

Comment: Thanks!  If you're accepting this as the answer,  I would appreciate it if you marked it as the "accepted answer" by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.join()`:

```
print('Test:', ','.join(map(str, [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i])))
```

The `map()` call makes sure all values are strings first.

Demo:

```
>>> a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i = range(1, 10)
>>> print('Test:', ','.join(map(str, [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i])))
Test: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining iterables is one of the most frustrating things for newcomers to Python to learn. There is no join method for lists, for example.

The rationale is that this is a string method. It makes sense, since it returns a string.

However, a builtin join() function that takes an iterable and the string by which to join the items in it would make a lot of sense and get support from me.

The upside of Python, however, is that there are very few of these basic but counter-intuitive operations out there.